# JS not passing value to html div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code in one of my MVC views:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    getTotal();
    CalculateDays();
});


$("#form1").on("input", function() {
    getTotal();
    CalculateDays();
});

function getTotal(){
var totalcart = 0;
    $('#form1 > table').each(function() {
        $(this).find("tr").each(function(){
            if( $( this ).has( ".inputdays" ).length > 0){
               var total = $(this).find(".inputquantity").find("input").val() * $(this).find(".hotelprice").html() * $(this).find(".inputdays").find("input").val();
               $(this).find("#hoteltotal").text(total);
               totalcart += total;
            }else{
                var total = $(this).find(".inputquantity").html() * $(this).find(".price").html();
               $(this).find("#carttotal").text(total);
               totalcart += total;
            }
        });
    });
    $("#total").html(totalcart);
}

function CalculateDays(){
    $('#form1 > table').each(function() {
        $(this).find("tr").each(function(){
            var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
            var today = new Date();
            // datetimepicker1
            $(this).find("#datetimepicker1").find("input").attr("min", calc_date(today, 0));
            var firstDate = new Date($(this).find("#datetimepicker1").find("input").val() + "T00:00:00");

            // datetimepicker2
            $(this).find("#datetimepicker2").find("input").attr("min", calc_date(firstDate, 1));
            var secondDate =  new Date($(this).find("#datetimepicker2").find("input").val() + "T00:00:00");

            // difference dtp1 and dtp2
            var date1_ms = firstDate.getTime()
            var date2_ms = secondDate.getTime()
            var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms) + 86400000;
            diffDays = Math.round(difference_ms/oneDay);

            // datetimepicker3
            $(this).find("#datetimepicker3").find("input").attr("min", calc_date(today, 0));
            $(this).find("#datetimepicker3").find("input").attr("max", calc_date(today, 14));

            if((!isNaN(diffDays)) && (firstDate.getTime() <= secondDate.getTime())){

                $(this).find(".inputdays").find("input").val(diffDays);
            }
            else{
                $(this).find(".inputdays").find("input").val("0");
            }
            getTotal();
        });
    });
}

function calc_date(currentday, adddays){
    currentday.setDate(currentday.getDate() + adddays);
    var dd = currentday.getDate();
    var mm = currentday.getMonth()+ 1;
    var yyyy = currentday.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    }

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    }
    var myday = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    return myday;
}

</script>

    }
```

This code just calculates input values, as seen on this picture:

[image: Problem]

As you can see, for Lines and Hotels, calculating the values works. But the for the actual total, no value is shown at the bottom of the page. The totalcart just gets parsed with the last line of code:

```
$("#total").html(totalcart);
```

My html looks like this, only including relevant part (it's a bit slovenly, I know):

```
`  <tr class="table">
                    <td id="shoppingcart">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Cart[i].Departure)
                    </td>
                    <td id="shoppingcart">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Cart[i].StartTime) 
                    </td>
                    <td id="shoppingcart">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Cart[i].Destination) 
                    </td>
                    <td id="shoppingcart">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Cart[i].ArrivalTime)
                    </td>
                    <td id="shoppingcart">
                        <div id='datetimepicker3'>
                            <input type='date' class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td id="shoppingcart" class="price">
                        @{var Subtotaal = Model.Cart[i].Price + Model.Class[i].Price;}
                        @Subtotaal
                    </td>
                    <td id="shoppingcart" class="inputquantity">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Cart[i].Quantity, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </td>

                    <td id="shoppingcart">
                        <div class="subtotal">
                            &#8364; <span id="carttotal"></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td id="shoppingcart">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Remove from cart", "DeleteCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.Cart[i].Line_id }, null)
                    </td>
                    <td id="shoppingcart">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Choose hotel", "GetHotelsbyCity", "Hotel", new { city = Model.Cart[i].Destination }, null)
                    </td>
                </tr>

                            for (var j = 0; j < Model.Cart[i].Quantity; j++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="shoppingcart" class="inputquantity">
                                        @Html.Label("First Name:", "First Name:", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="shoppingcart" class="inputquantity">
                                        @Html.TextBox("First Name", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="shoppingcart" class="inputquantity">
                                        @Html.Label("Last Name:", "Last Name:", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="shoppingcart" class="inputquantity">
                                        @Html.TextBox("Last Name", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                            }
            <tr>
                </table>
    }
    <hr />
    if (Model.Hotel != null)
    {
        <h3>Hotel</h3>
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tr class="table">
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hotel[0].Name)

                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hotel[0].Adress)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hotel[0].Price) (€)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hotel[0].Quantity)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hotel[0].Checkin)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hotel[0].Checkout)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hotel[0].Days)
                                            </th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Hotel.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Hotel[i].Hotel_id)
                                            <tr class="table">
                                                <td id="shoppingcart">
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Hotel[i].Name) 
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="shoppingcart">
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Hotel[i].Adress) 
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="shoppingcart" class="hotelprice">
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Hotel[i].Price) 
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="shoppingcart" class="inputquantity">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Hotel[i].Quantity, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="shoppingcart">
                                                    @*Datepicker werkt met input id en moet unieke id's hebben bij td, maar dit aanpassen hielp niet*@
                                                @*<td>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <input id='datetimepicker1' type='date' class="form-control" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <input id='datetimepicker2' type='date' class="form-control" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>*@
                                                    <div id='datetimepicker1'>
                                                        <input type='date' class="form-control" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="shoppingcart">
                                                    <div id='datetimepicker2'>
                                                        <input type='date' class="form-control" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="shoppingcart" class="inputdays">
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Hotel[i].Days, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
                                                </td>

                                                <td id="shoppingcart">
                                                    <div class="subtotal">
                                                         &#8364; <span id="hoteltotal"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td id="shoppingcart">
                                                    @Html.ActionLink("Remove from cart", "DeleteHotel", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.Hotel[i].Hotel_id }, null)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                        <tr>
                                    </table>
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Raw("No hotels selected, please check owr hotels:") @Html.ActionLink("Choose hotel", "Index", "Hotel")
    }

    <div id="cart-total" class="total">
        <span>Total:</span> &#8364; <span id="total"></span>
    </div>
}
                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
@Html.Raw("Your shoppingcart is empty at the moment")
                                                                }

<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-default" @Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Payment", "ShoppingCart")
        <a class="btn btn-default" @Html.ActionLink("Continue Shopping", "Index", "Line")
    </div>
</div>`
```

What is the problem here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried .text() instead of .html()

Comment: Where is `getTotal()` called from?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible code snippet, or an online page where bug happens? Without it, we may need to guess from your JavaScript code.

Comment: I have tried .text() instead of html, now it's showing NaN? What is the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see where in your code, you are triggering `getTotal` it's a common mistake

I cannot see how the other code works so I can't say but the function by itself will not run, it will need to be triggered by an event or called in your code either like this;

```
    function getTotal(){
      ...
    }

    // run the function
    getTotal();
```

or it could be self invoked like this;

```
    (function getTotal(){
      ...
    })()
```

Comment: Why should it be triggered? For the hotels and lines, real time calculation works. But not for the actual total. Why does it work for those and not for the actual total, when it's in the same form?

Comment: I cannot see how the other code works so I can't say but the function by itself will not run, it will need to be triggered by an event or called in your code.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I included the full JS script I'm using now. The method getTotal() gets called. I thought I included all scripts. Truly sorry about that, it is late here and I'm in desperate need for a solution.

Comment: can you also check the parts you are getting html for are actually returning an integer or at least a string of an integer? like `$(this).find(".hotelprice").html()`

Comment: td class "hotelprice" retrieves data from my HotelVM, which has Price set as  `public double Price { get; set; }` is the problem here then, since it's not an int, but a double?

Comment: The problem could come from either "hotelprice" or "price". make sure they are recognized by javascript as integers. But I've also just spotted something else which you need to fix first. In your else statement you are doing this;

`$(this).find(".inputquantity").html()`

this is getting the html of input quantity which i'm pretty sure is html for a label and input field.